# Определить вид связи в сложном предложении

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Помогите разобраться с видами связи и типом придаточных в предложении.

Только иногда глаза его отдыхали на нетронутых огнем зеленых разливах проса, а потом снова расстилалась по обеим сторонам дороги выжженная земля, такая страшная в своей молчаливой печали, что временами Звягинцев не мог на нее смотреть.

Склоняюсь к варианту с подчинительной связью, но сбивает с толку сочинительный союз "а" (а потом снова расстилалась...)

Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Отметьте полезность ответа как принято на сайте!

Answer (score 1):

```
  Склоняюсь к варианту с подчинительной связью, но сбивает с толку сочинительный 
  союз "а"
```

А что,  сочинительной и подчинительной связи в одном предложении не бывает?

[Только иногда глаза его отдыхали на нетронутых огнем зеленых разливах проса], а [потом снова расстилалась по обеим сторонам дороги выжженная земля, такая страшная в своей молчаливой печали], (что временами Звягинцев не мог на нее смотреть). Cложное предложение с сочинением и подчинением, состоит из трёх простых. Первое и второе соединены сочинительной связью, второе и третье - подчинительной. Второе осложнено обособленным определением, выраженным прилагательным с зависимыми словами. Третье предложение придаточное меры и степени.

Виды связи определяются по союзам и союзным словам. А - сочинительный противительный союз, связь сочинительная; что - подчинительный союз, связь подчинительная.

Comment: Спасибо большое!